# Scrolling/Sorting/Searching/Swapping two really long lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have two really long lists of People, ~20,000 each, but only one list is displayed at a given time.  Each Person has a Name, Nickname, and Age.  The goal is to display each and every person in a list that can be scrolled, sorted, and searched efficiently.  In addition, I need to be able to swap between lists.  I have been able to create the desired functionality, but the individual operations are not very user friendly. The scrolling is not smooth and sorting/searching/swapping can freeze the UI for a second or two, and sometimes the page will even crash.  Therefore I am looking for improvements on the following code, and am wondering if a smooth user experience is even possible with lists of this size without having to use virtual rendering (only populating the DOM with what is visible by the viewport and faking the scroll bar).  Thanks in advance!

The Javascript is structured as:

```
var groupOne =
[
    {name: "Michael", nickname: "Mike", age: 23},
    {name: "Matthew", nickname: "Matt", age: 25},
    {name: "Aaron", nickname: "Ron", age: 30},
    ...
]

var groupTwo =
[
    {name: "Joseph", nickname: "Joe", age: 20},
    {name: "Carter", nickname: "C", age: 30},
    {name: "William", nickname: "Will", age: 40},
    ...
]
```

A Person is displayed as:

```
---------------------------------
|           Name         |      |
-------------------------|  Age |
|           Nickname     |      |
---------------------------------
```

The HTML is structured as:

```
<input id="search" type="text">
<button id="sort"></button>
<button id="swap"></button>

<ol id="people">
    <li class="person" data-name="Michael" data-nickname="Mike" data-age="23">
        <p class="name">Michael</p>
        <p class="nickname">Mike</p>
        <p class="age">23</p>
    </li>
    <li class="person" data-name="Matthew" data-nickname="Matt" data-age="25">
        <p class="name">Matthew</p>
        <p class="nickname">Matt</p>
        <p class="age">25</p>
    </li>
    <li class="person" data-name="Aaron" data-nickname="Ron" data-age="30">
        <p class="name">Aaron</p>
        <p class="nickname">Ron</p>
        <p class="age">30</p>
    </li>
    ...
</ol>
```

The code for searching is:

```
$("#search").change(function ()
{
    var search = $(this).val();

    var list = document.getElementById("people");

    var items = list.children;

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        var item = items[i];
        var name = item.getAttribute("data-name");

        if(search == "")
        {
            item.style.display = "block";
        }
        else if(name.indexOf(search) != -1)
        {
            item.style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            item.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
});
```

The code for sorting is:

```
$("#sort").click(function ()
{
    var list = document.getElementById("people");

    var items = list.children;

    var itemArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        itemArray.push(items[i]);
    }

    itemArray.sort(function (a, b)
    {
        var nameA = a.getAttribute("data-name");
        var nameB = b.getAttribute("data-name");
        return nameA.localeCompare(nameB);
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
    {
        list.appendChild(itemArray[i]);
    }
});
```

The code for swapping is:

```
$("#swap").click(function ()
{  
    var $people = $("#people");
    $people.empty();

    for(var i = 0; i < groupTwo.length; i++)
    {
        var person = groupTwo[i];

        var container = document.createElement("li");
        container.className = "person";
        container.setAttribute("data-name", person.name);
        container.setAttribute("data-nickname", person.nickname);
        container.setAttribute("data-age", person.age);

        var nameParagraph = document.createElement("p");
        nameParagraph.className = "name";
        nameParagraph.textContent = person.name;

        var nicknameParagraph = document.createElement("p");
        nicknameParagraph.className = "nickname";
        nicknameParagraph.textContent = person.nickname;

        var ageParagraph = document.createElement("p");
        ageParagraph.className = "age";
        ageParagraph.textContent = person.age;

        container.appendChild(nameParagraph);
        container.appendChild(nicknameParagraph);
        container.appendChild(ageParagraph);

       $people.append(container);
    }
});
```

Discoveries so far:

- Absolute Positioning really hurts smoothness of scrolling
- Using nested divs for positioning really improves scrolling but hurts swapping via $.empty(), sorting via $.append(), and even causes crashes
- Inline Block seems to be better for scrolling than float
- Table Layout may improve scrolling but doesn't help with swapping/sorting